# How to modify my method to search and then remove duplicates in O(N) or O(N * log N)?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, time-complexity

I created a method which search for duplicates and then stores duplicates index into another array. Then I'm running through my big array and move all entries without duplicates.

Now, my problem is that this uses O(N*N) and I am using additional memory space since I am adding additional array.

How could this be done? **Assuming that I need to understand how this could be done without using additional libraries or HashSet.**

Any tips appreciated.

```
   public void dups()
   {
       int[] index = new int[100];

       int k = 0;
       int n = 0;
       int p = 0;

       for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
           for (int j = i + 1; j < elements; j++)
               if(a[j].equals(a[i]))
                   index[k++] = i;

       for (int m = 0; m < elements; m++)
           if (m != index[p])
               a[n++] = (T) a[m];
           else
               p++;

       elements -= k;
   }
```

Comment: It's impossible to remove duplicates in O(N).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395668/remove-duplicates-from-array-without-using-hash-table

Comment: He doesn't say that hash tables are not to be used.

Comment: Not to split hairs, but O(n) can be done using a HashMap.  But I'm not sure if the "no HashSet" requirement includes HashMap or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't find duplicates in `O(n)` (in general).**

However it is possible in **`O(n*log n)`**. Simply sort your array (`O(n*log n)`), and then the scanning for duplicates can be done in `O(n)`.

On the other hand, if you can use hash tables (what you probably don't want to do, if you don't want to use any additional libraries) you can scan through the array and count how often each element appears in the array. After that, you can go through each element in the hash table and find those elements that appeared more than once. This would take an **expected** runtime of **`O(n)`**, but not deterministic `O(n)`.

**Finally, why did I write that you can't find duplicates in `O(n)` in general?**
One could imagine several special cases, where finding duplicates is possible in `O(n)`. 
For example, your array could only contain numbers from 0 to 99. 
In that case, you could use another array (of size 100) to count how often each element appears in the array. This works the same way as with the hash table, but its runtime would be deterministic `O(n)`.

Another example where finding duplicates is possible in `O(n)` is of course, if the array is already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashSet` to do this in O(n) time:

```
public <T> int removeDups(T[] original) {
    HashSet<T> unique = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T item: original) {
        unique.add(item);
    }

    int size = unique.size();
    int curr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i += 1) {
        if (unique.remove(original[i])) {
            original[curr] = original[i];
            curr++;
        }
    }

    return size;
}
```

Be aware that this depends on the `hashCode` method of your list elements properly distributing elements over the buckets in the `HashSet` to achieve O(n). In worst case, this is O(n*m), where m is the number of unique elements, so you should definitely measure it.

This implementation modifies the array in place, and returns the number of unique elements. Although the array may be larger than this, elements past that point should considered garbage.

It makes one pass over the list to add items to the `HashSet` (adding an item is O(1)), and another pass to update the array, so it's O(n) (again, assuming a good hash function).

Comment: This is not O(n), but O(n) *expected* (since a hash operates in constant *expected* time, not constant time).

Comment: I probably should not make my program using additional memory by creating another ArrayList.

Comment: @HelpNeeder -- that sounds like a [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) to me.

Comment: @leemes In this case, O(n) expected might be perfectly fine, and could easily be an improvement over O(n^2) or O(n*log n).

Comment: @Brigham The worst case scenario of hash tables is worse than O(n*log n). It is *impossible* to find duplicates in deterministic linear time, that's all I wanted to emphasize.

Comment: @HelpNeeder I modified the algorithm to modify the array in place, so the only extraneous data structure is the HashSet.

Comment: @leemes I added a note that in worst case it's O(n*m) to emphasize that he should measure it with his dataset.

Comment: This is still not correct. `m` should be the number of hash collisions, not duplicates. Given a bad hash function or evil input (made to purposely force hash collisions), every number of the array will go to the same hash node and has to be put in a list at this hash node. This will give quadratic runtime. While this is a very pessimistic scenario, it should still be considered where time is security critical. A nice example worth reading is [Hash-algorithm-collision DoS attack](http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/weblog/30)

Comment: @leemes I said m was the number of **unique** elements, not the number of duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, but I mean hash collisions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17770/discussion-between-brigham-and-leemes)

Answer (score 1):

```
array1 = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,4,4,5,5,5,5,10,10,8,7,7,9,10]

array1.sort() # sorting is must
print(array1)

current = NONE
count = 0 

# overwriting the numbers at the frontal part of the array
for item in array1:
    if item != current:
        array1[count] = item
        count +=1
        current=item
        
       

print(array1)#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10]

print(array1[:count])#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The most Efficient method is :

```
array1 = [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,4,4,5,5,5,5,10,10,8,7,7,9,10]

array1.sort()
print(array1)

print([*dict.fromkeys(array1)])#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

#OR#
aa = list(dict.fromkeys(array1))
print( aa)#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not O(n) because of the hash and equals comparisons, and uses LinkedHashSet, which is part of the Java standard library, but probably close enough:

```
public void dups() {
    Set<Integer> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        uniques.add(elements[i]);
    }
    // todo: copy the set into a list, then call toArray() to get an array.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of a HashMap is array based and is O(n).  Consequently, if you want a fun exercise, you can sift through the implementation of the HashMap to understand exactly how  it hashes its keys.  Basically, it uses the key's hashCode and uses it to index an array in predetermined location (hashCode & arraylength - 1), and stores the value at that index.  If you were to repeat the concept, using the value as both the key and the value, you would have only unique entries in your array.

You will, however, end up with an array with a lot of empty slots, if you have a large number of duplicates, but only unique values.  Once you populate the array, you only need to loop through it once to remove any empty slots. (ex: copy all non-null entries to a List)

It would be O(n), but required 2 passes - once to populate the array and once to remove the empty slots.  It would also require an additional array of same length as your existing array,  and a smaller array (or list) for a final list of unique values.