# Removing duplicates in an Array-based unsorted list without sets

Tags: java

Consider the operation `removeAll`, which removes all occurrences of element from a list.
The method returns the number of elements removed.

```
public int removeAll(E element)
```

Implement this operation for:
1. Array-based unsorted list

we cant use sets.

What i have started for now:

```
  public int removeAll(T element) {

int duplicatesRemoved = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j <= array.length - 1; j++) {
    if (array[i] == array[j]) {

    }
  }
```

I'm unable to get the rest done, any help please?

Comment: Check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395668/remove-duplicates-from-array-without-using-hash-table)

Comment: Going to end up with O(n^2) which is bad. "Java 2 Security Model" implementation actually does exactly this.

Comment: Do you want to remove an element or List of elements ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained i want to remove duplicate elements from an array based unsorted list without using sets. i want it to return the number of duplicates we deleted.

Comment: Then why that parameter `T element`. Sorry that makes me think that you want to remove `element` from the `List`.

Comment: @NoobUnChained sorry noob i got confused, the element you enter, your searching for it and if it has duplicates, it will delete it's duplicates and return how many times you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the contents in a `collection of some sort since you're not allowed to use Set`, then pull out what's in the collection.

Arrays (the class, not primitive arrays) support a contains method, but you'll be iterating over the new collection everytime, making it inefficient.

Or if you can't use Array either, you can do it in a primitive array, just walking through looking for duplicates, over and over.

Comment: were not allowed to use sets

Comment: ridiculous assignment.  A Set is really the right answer.   But if you can't do that, you'll have to use some other collection.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you set the duplicate elements to something like `null`.  After you've removed all duplicates, compact the array by swapping non-null elements at the end with the null elements in the middle.

Alternatively, create an empty array, and move non-duplicate elements to the new array.

Comment: the problem is im unable to go forward. I don't know what to do next, this assignment is confusing me.

Comment: You're already identifying the duplicates, now you just need to remove them.  Set the duplicate elements to some value that isn't in the original array, like array[j] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; in your inner and outer loops, skip over array elements that have been set to Integer.MIN_VALUE.  When you're finished removing duplicates, then overwrite all Integer.MIN_VALUE elements with valid elements towards the end of the array, until all MIN_VALUE elements are at the end of the array, preceded by valid array elements.

Answer (score 0):

As this seems homework, no explanation, but this puzzle:

```
int lengthWithValues = array.length;
for (int i = 0; i < lengthWithValues; i++) {
    // Loop invariant: for all at < i array is sorted, unique and complete.
    int valueToBeChecked = array[i];
    for (int k = i + 1, int j = i + 1; k < lengthWithValues; j++) {
        if (array[j] == valueToBeChecked) {
            --lengthWithValues; // Remove duplicate
        } else {
            array[k] = array[j]; // Maintain differing from all at <= i.
            ++k;
        }
    }
}
duplicatesRemoved = array.length - lengthWithValues;
// array[0 .. length - duplicatesRemoved] is the unique array.
int[] uniqueArray = new int[lengthWithValues];
System.arrayCopy(array, 0, uniqueArray, 0, lengthWithValues);
```

Comment: bro, this isn't a homework assignement. I'm doing some revision only.

Comment: @user2272227  I'm confused.  It's not a homework assignment, but it is an assignment, and you're not allowed to use Sets.

Comment: @CPerkins this is a question in my book and im solving them all for my midterm. Revision. thats why i need a right working solution

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Use a Map.

### More answer

Here is an algorithm, it is functional, but can be improved:

Create a Map<T, Boolean>.  The second parameter type is whatever you want, I chose Boolean.
Create a new array named newArray; this will contain the unique values.
Iterate through the array.  For each item perform the following:

1. Using the current arrayValue as the key, get the storedValue from the map.
2. if the storedValue is null (i.e. the Map.get() returned null) then this is a unique item.  Insert the arrayValue, Boolean.TRUE into the map and add the arrayValue to the newArray.
3. if the storedValue is not null, then increment the duplicate count.

After iterating through the list, the newArray contains all non-duplicates and the duplicate count contains the count of duplicates.

Comment: i dont need to return an array or anything. The method just removes duplicates of the element you ask it to seach for and then returns the count of how many times it deleted.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
 /**
 * This method removes all duplicates from an array named "array"
 * using a temporary List. So it converts the array into 
 * something like a Java set
 * 
 * @return int number of duplicates removed
 */
public static int removeAll() {
    int duplicates = 0;
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        Object element = array[i];
        if(list.contains(element)) {
            duplicates++;
        }
        else {
            list.add(element);
        }
    }
    array = list.toArray();
    return duplicates;
}
```

2.

```
/**
 * This method removes duplicates from an array named "array" using a
 * temporary List.
 * @param elementToBeRemoved
 * @return int number of duplicates removed
 */
public static int removeAll(Object elementToBeRemoved) {
    int duplicates = 0;
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Object element = array[i];
        if (list.contains(elementToBeRemoved)) {
            duplicates++;
        } else {
            list.add(element);
        }
    }
    array = list.toArray();
    return duplicates;
}
```

Comment: I cant use lists or sets. I need to do it as basic as i can.